# globally suppress c++ std::cout when testing

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

I have a Struct point at numerical data with a returnNext() method that returns AND posts in stdout the next datum each time called. I also have a series of unit tests that use this method: in those tests I want to supress all Data's std::cout's so that I only check the validity of the returned values without bloating the screen with messages. e.g.

```
struct Data { 
  Data(int n): datum{n} {};
  int datum;
  int returnNext() { 
    std::cout << datum << " returned" << std::endl;
    return datum;
  }
}

// main.cpp
int main() {
  Data d{100};
  d.returnNext(); // I want this to print at the screen 
  return 0;
}

// test.cpp
int main() {
  TEST( ... ) {
    Data d{100};
    ASSERT_THAT(d.returnNext(), 100); // I want just to check the output, not to check
  }
std::cout << "some message" << std::endl; // I want this printed
return 0;
}
```

An obvious solution would be to use pre-compiler flags/commands to exclude the std::cout from TEST builds. But this would require editing several modules and would also make my code ugly.

Another case would be to use redirect stdout to dev/null from the console, but this would also suppress the stdout my test modules.

Isn't there a way to programmatically supress/redirect stdout during particular moments in a program's lifetime???

Comment: You could use a logger with different level of precision and choose at runtime what to print.

Comment: You can create a log stream class with various levels of verbosity.

Comment: Why not use `/dev/null`?

Comment: Anyone know what the -1 was for? 
Seems a good question to me :)

Answer (score 13):

For the general problem of suppressing `std::cout`, you can use [`std::basic_ios::rdbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) with a null buffer:

```
auto old_buffer = std::cout.rdbuf(nullptr);
```

To restore it, just do

```
std::cout.rdbuf(old_buffer);
```

Comment: Interesting I hadn't seen that before :) Maybe you could elaborate on how you would use this to suppress the `returnNext()` without suppressing any output from the unit test framework?

Comment: Nice trick, worth noting for other contexts, but as a global modifier it is much too general for the asked question.

Comment: Note that this process is _reversible_ - `rdbuf()` returns the previous stream buffer, so you can save the return value of this function and then restore it later.

Answer (score 5):

This is precisely why having hard-coded stdout output in your member functions is a bad idea. Now you think you have to block `std::cout` globally, because your class's behaviour is inflexible.

Instead, move the `std::cout` call someplace else (to make its use optional) or have it be an arbitrary `std::ostream` which you can make route to nowhere.